# Executing remote command in Vertica using Python

Tags: python, ssh, vertica

I'm trying to execute a remote command like this:

```
ssh root@192.168.1.2 'su - vertica -c "vsql -c \"select * from tableName where timestamp > '2016-05-15 00:00:00' limit 1 \" "'"
```

It gives me an error

```
ERROR 4856:  Syntax error at or near "00" at character 61
LINE 1: ...rom tableName where timestamp > 2016-05-15 00:00:00 l...
```

Although when I execute this query directly in the remote machine, it works just fine.

Can someone provide any clues here please ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those outside quotes on the ssh command. This should work fine (I also fixed some quoting mistake you had at the end):

```
ssh root@192.168.1.2 su - vertica -c "vsql -c \"select * from tableName where timestamp > '2016-05-15 00:00:00' limit 1 \" "
```

I feel like I really have to mention here though that you shouldn't be doing this. Why ssh to a root account to run a job under another user? Why not just ssh to that user directly?  Create a private key, add the public to the authorized_keys list and do this instead:

```
ssh vertica@192.168.2.1 /opt/vertica/bin/vsql -c \"select \* from tableName where timestamp \> \'2016-05-15 00:00:00\' limit 1 \"
```

Notice that I escaped more characters in this version though.

The only trick will be your shell variables if you need them.  You might need to run bash or source the .bashrc (although be warned in some distributions, there is a block in the .bashrc for noninteractive shells that may need to be fixed).